# Select a calendar dialog window from console app

Tags: swift, macos

I have a console app written with Swift to add events and reminders. I need be able to show 'select calendar' dialog from it. Is there any standar way to show this dialog or it needs to be created manually using NSAlert?

Sorry, kind of newbie in mac development, need this console app to interact with macos through electron app.

[image: Calendar dialog]

Comment: This is a standard `NSAlert` with a custom `accessoryView`

Comment: yes, but I need to pull calendars, add colors to combobox, etc. by myself... Wondering is there any existing component...

Comment: No, there isn't, but pulling calendars and adding colors is not that hard 

Comment: could you please advise how to implement those colorful boxes before calendar name

Comment: They are just images. Use a custom `NSView` class which draws the shape in `draw(_ rect)` and implement a property  `image` which returns an `NSImage` via `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay` and `cacheDisplay`. Assign the image to the image view of the menu item.